# How do I take over a value sent by a "null form" redirecting to another controller?

Tags: forms, variables, cakephp

This is my form:

```
echo $this->Form->create(null, array('url' => '/offices/addOffice'));
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden', 
                                    'value' => $this->data['Agency']['id'])); 
echo $this->Form->end(__('Add Office', true));
```

Now in the addOffice function I would like to get the value sent from this form.

What I did is:

```
function addOffice($id = null){
    $this->set(compact('id'));
}
```

but it doesn't send the $id to the view. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking, because if you want to "get the value sent from this form", then "send the $id to the view" doesn't have anything to do with it.

If you want to retrieve the the data from the form, you shouldn't put `null` as the model's name. Use the relevant model, which I assume is "Office" in this case.

```
echo $this->Form->create('Office', array('url' => '/offices/addOffice'));
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden', 
                                    'value' => $this->data['Agency']['id']));
```

Now the id can be retrieved from `$this->data[ 'Office' ][ 'id' ]` in the controller.

If the question is how you can set the id in the first place using the function parameter, you have to use the `$id` parameter you've set in the controller:

```
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden', 
                                    'value' => $id));
```